# jQuery Dialog form serialize reposting incorrect data on subsequent uses

Tags: javascript, ajax, webforms, jquery-dialog

I'm working with forms inside jQuery Dialog, and am having some issues with the data it's posting. First load and save works fine, posts the correct data. Until I refresh the page though, every subsequent load seems to work, as in the correct data is in the form, however, when saved, the data from the first load is what is posted every time.

```
function formdialog(url, tack, divid, scriptload){
    $.getJSON(url+tack+"/form", function(data){
        var formwin = '<div><form id="formdialog">'+data['form']+'</form></div>';
        var dialog = $(formwin).dialog({
            title: data['title'],
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Save": function(){    
                    $.post(url+tack+"/process", 
                        $("#formdialog").serialize(),
                        function(data){
                            alert($("#formdialog").serialize());
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                            $(this).remove();
                        }
                    );
                },
                "Cancel": function(){$(this).dialog('close'); $(this).remove();}
            }
        });

        dialog.dialog("open");
    });
}

$(function(){        
    $("a.edlnk").click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        formdialog(CONFIG_HREF_SITE+"ajax/"+appControl, "/"+url, divid);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is the

```
$(this).dialog('close');
$(this).remove();
```

...in your `post` callback, because you haven't specified the context for the callback. If so, changing the `post` to this should fix it:

```
$.ajax({
    url:        url+tack+"/process",
    type:       'POST',
    data:       $("#formdialog").serialize(),
    context:    this,
    success:    function(data){
        alert($("#formdialog").serialize());
        $(this).dialog('close');
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

...because then you're preserving the meaning of `this` when the `success` function is called.

So why would that issue cause the behavior you're seeing? Because if you're not removing the `formwin` `div`, you're not removing the `formdialog` `form`, which means you end up with multiple `form`s on the page with the same ID. Although having the same ID on multiple elements is invalid and therefore subject to undefined behavior, *most* browsers will give you the *first* matching element when you ask for an element by ID — which in your case would be the earlier form with the earlier data.

---

**Edit** Re your comment: Yeah, I kind of missed the `$(this).dialog('close')` there. :-) A couple of options: One is to remember `$(formwin)` in a local variable and then use it in the callback, e.g.:

```
var formwin = '<div><form id="formdialog">'+data['form']+'</form></div>';
var formwinElement = $(formwin);     // <== Remember it here
var dialog = formwinElement.dialog({ // <== Use it here

// ...

                $.post(url+tack+"/process", 
                    $("#formdialog").serialize(),
                    function(data){
                        alert($("#formdialog").serialize());
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        formWinElement.remove(); // <== And again here
                    }
                );
```

...and don't bother with the `context` param (hence my using your original `$.post` in this update). That works because the `post` success handler is a closure over the `formwinElement` variable (and several other things).

Comment: Data posting works great now. Problem is that the dialog now does not close. Suggestions?